# remove all special character from string java

Tags: java, android

I wanted to know how I can do to completely eliminate **ALL** of the special characters from a string. In other words I would leave only the words, thus eliminating any other characters as +-òç@èé etc.

Now i use

```
myString =  Normalizer.normalize(myString, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

But some characters speacials still remain.

Comment: Define "special characters".  E.g. `é` is an ASCII letter which can be in a word so your question does not contain enough information.

Comment: Just make a filtering function that returns your string after replacing each unwanted character with "".

Comment: `@#+èé<>§ù` - only remove these characters?  All other characters are OK?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace the `\p{ASCII}` regex class with a stricter set that only contains the chars you allow. For example,

```
myString =  Normalizer.normalize(myString, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

will first decompose accented chars like `é` to two parts `e` + `combining ´` (normal form D) and then the regex will remove any character that is not ASCII a..z or A..Z.

Answer (score 0):

The default charset is unicode (utf-8) in java ,The below code uses the unicode representation of a  character and checks if the unicode of a character is speicial character;
The solution given below is of the  Time complexity = O(n);

```
public class RemoveSpecialCharacters {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

private static boolean isSpecialCharacter(int b)
{
    if((b>=32 && b<=47 )||(b>=58 && b<=64)||(b>=91 && b<=96) ||(b>=123 && b<=126)||b>126)
        return true;
    return false;


}
public static String removeSpecialCharacters(String a)
{
    StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer(a);


    int lenvar=s.length();
    String myString="";
    for(int i=0;i<lenvar;i++)
    {


        if(!isSpecialCharacter(s.charAt(i)))
        {
            myString+=s.charAt(i);


        }

    }
    return myString;


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(removeSpecialCharacters("fleCKHE)_+_+"));



}


}
```

o/p:fleCKHE